# Keeping isc-dhcp-server running even if there's no subnet

Tags: dhcp, isc-dhcpd

I use isc-dhcp-server to provide IP addresses to some instruments that connect intermittently via a USB-to-Ethernet adapter, addresses in the 192.168.1.0/24 range.
If the adapter is not connected when dhcpd starts, then it quits and won't be available when the time comes, unless I do a service restart.

Since this system is meant to be used by various people I'd like to keep things simple by keeping isc-dhcp-server running even if there's no connection. Is there an option for that?

Thanks

Comment: Run dhcp server via udev rules when adding that interface.

Comment: Something like RUN+="systemctl restart isc-dhcp-server.service" ? But won't that overide what Linux normally does with the interface ?